# Is there a built-in charting library in iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, charts, ios9

I'm currently working on an app where I need to displa charts like in the added picture. I already know about ios-charts framework, etc.

But I really like the charts from iOS 9 health app landscape mode. It's showing current value when touching:

[image]

Now I'm wondering if this kind of chart is available for developers from Apple in iOS 9, because I already saw it in some other 3rd party apps (e.g. Idealo app for iPad (Germany))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no native Chart library in iOS. There are however, plenty of libraries available. Unfortunately, you will need to dig through them to find the one closest to what you've seen.

Of course, you could also reach out to the developers of the apps you like and ask them directly. Most developers like to share information like that.